# How to Handle the same Folder names in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, lotus-notes

We are doing the Migration of Lotus notes to SharePoint.
In lotus notes i am having same name of Top folder subfolder.Like below

*Folder1*

Folder2~**Folder1**

Here in this sub-folder **Folder1** having items.But these items are migrated to top-folder *Folder1* in SharePoint. How to handle this scenario.

Comment: You should review your migration scripts. SHarePoint can handle nested folders just fine. Please include details on how you migrate the data.

Comment: we are creating batch files and migrating data using created job from quest tool